# I don't know how I can get the subdata in a JSON file with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have this JSON file:

```
{"__v":4,"_id":"53dbeedb1a6550ee08c55c05","name":"Quatro formaggi","ingredients":["53c791b6e4b04af47f662f98","53c791b6e4b04af47f662f98","53c791b6e4b04af47f662f98","53c791b6e4b04af47f662f98"]}
```

I want get every ingredients. If I write:

```
{{pizza.ingredients}}
```

I get:

```
["53c791b6e4b04af47f662f98","53c791b6e4b04af47f662f98","53c791b6e4b04af47f662f98","53c791b6e4b04af47f662f98"]
```

If I write this:

```
{{pizza.ingredients.1}}
```

I get this:

```
53c791b6e4b04af47f662f98
```

but I want a loop that I can get every ingredient like this result:

```
1- 53c791b6e4b04af47f662f98
2- 53c79214e4b04af47f662f9d
3- 53c7925ae4b04af47f662fa0
```

how can I do that with AngularJS?

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: All suggestion is good for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> sorry I have confused and I copied to JSON file with all pizzas. But
>   now I have changed the JSON file with one pizza and I want get the
>   ingredients with one pizza. If I write this: ing pizza.ingredients I
>   get this error: Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.19/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=i%20in%20pizza.ingredients&‌​p1=string%3A53c791b6e4b04af47f662f98
>   ...
>
> @Dominuskernel ohhhhh that is because you can't have duplicates in
>   repeater, see here docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes –

You right @Mritunjay

The code corrected is:

```
<div>
    <p>{{pizza.name}}</p>   
        <div ng-repeat="ing in pizza.ingredients track by $index">
            <p>{{ing}}</p>
        </div>      
</div>
```

My problem is explained in [this link.](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes)

Answer (score 0):

I am not giving you exact output, but after some modification you should get it.

Do it like bellow

```
<div ng-repeat="piz in pizza">
   {{$index+1}}--  {{piz.ingredients.0}}
</div>
```

Output

```
1-- 53c791b6e4b04af47f662f98
2-- 53c791f7e4b04af47f662f9b
3-- 53c79214e4b04af47f662f9d
```

Which is first element of each ingrediant.

Comment: sorry I have confused and I copied to JSON file with all pizzas. But now I have changed the JSON file with one pizza and I want get the ingredients with one pizza. If I write this: `ing pizza.ingredients` I get this error: `Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.19/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=i%20in%20pizza.ingredients&p1=string%3A53c791b6e4b04af47f662f98
v/<@http://localhost/api/angular.min.js:6:443
yd</<.link/<@http://localhost/api/angular.min.js:199:86
Zd/this.$get</k.prototype.$watchCollection/<@http://localhost/api/angular.min.js:109:65
Zd/this.$get</k.prototype.$digest@http://...`

Comment: @Dominuskernel ohhhhh that is because you can't have duplicates in repeater, see here https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes

Comment: @Dominuskernel you should accept answers or atleast upvote them if they are helpful